# Can't reboot after upgrading ubuntu 20.04 to 5.16 kernel

Tags: boot, 20.04, upgrade, kernel

I just upgraded to ubuntu 5.16 and I can't reboot into 5.16 directly.
I can reboot by going into 5.16 recovery menu and clicking on Resume in recovery.

I've following options for ubuntu
[image]

I ran GParted but I don't see anything abnormal.

How to fix it?

Comment: Using mainline kernels are largely unsupported. You're continuing at your own risk.

Comment: Ethernet and WiFi doesn't work for me on 5.11. Upgrading to 5.16 fixed it. Can't find any help or support on fixing it on 5.11.

Comment: I don't agree that troubleshooting an unsupported kernel on a supported release is off-topic, but I do think this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Running a [kernel intended for testing only](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) might not be the best way to solve your actual problem and may cause new problems, as it seems you are currently experiencing.  Generally it's better to provide details about and ask about your original problem.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /boot`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: In case of any doubt - we support Ubuntu regardless of the kernel https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17049/can-i-ask-about-a-problem-with-a-non-ubuntu-kernel-here

Comment: I actually didn't mean to implicate this was off-topic, but rather that it's an untested path to travel. Also, I was trying to indicate that running mainline kernels should probably only be an option for advanced users who has sufficient knowledge to sort out any arising issues. But I can see that these points were rather implicit and not as explicit as they could have been.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that kernel was not fully installed but it was just showing on the boot option. Not sure what that means. I completely removed 5.16 and I'm back to 5.11 and getting back to waste more time on figuring out how to fix networking issue.